# Setting EditIndex on a asp:GridView, can I be sure it is the correct row after rebinding to live data has been done?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Having an asp:GridView, when I put it into edit mode by setting EditIndex, I also need to update its data using the DataSource property and call DataBind like this:

```
protected void GrdFoo_OnRowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
  grdFoo.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
  grdFoo.DataSource = DataBase.GetFoos();
  grdFoo.DataBind();
}
```

Now, if the database contents was changed since I was populating the gridview first, how can I be sure I will edit the correct row?

## edit

I got the suggestion to use `OnRowDataBound`. I am using a command field to trigger `GrdFoo_OnRowEditing`. Is the use of `OnRowDataBound` still a good idea?

Here is how I use the CommandField (aspx):

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdFoo" runat="server"
    OnRowEditing="GrdFoo_OnRowEditing"
    OnRowCancelingEdit="GrdFoo_OnRowCancelingEdit"
    OnRowUpdating="GrdFoo_OnRowUpdating"
    OnRowDeleting="GrdFoo_OnRowDeleting"
    DataKeyNames="ID">
  <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label Text='<%#Eval("Name") %>' runat="server"/>
      </ItemTemplate>
      <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" Text='<%#Eval("Name") %>' runat="server"/>
      </EditItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Email">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label Text='<%#Eval("Email") %>' runat="server"/>
      </ItemTemplate>
      <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" Text='<%#Eval("Email") %>' runat="server"/>
      </EditItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True"
      ShowDeleteButton="True" buttontype="Image"
      DeleteImageUrl="delete.png"
      EditImageUrl="edit.png"
      CancelImageUrl="cancel.png"
      UpdateImageUrl="save.png"/>
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: try it in `OnRowDataBound` property

Comment: Question updated @Asif.Ali

Comment: In `RowDataBound` event you can check anything here as the binding of gridview is performed in this event

Comment: So I need to find out the id in GrdFoo_OnRowEditing for the clicked row and use that in the OnRowDataBound handler to know what to set EditIndex to?

Comment: No there is no need to find id `RowDataBound` provide check if gridview is in edit mode.

Comment: If you really are worried about editing the wrong row you have to cache the initial `DataBase.GetFoos()` and rebind that on edit etc. Then you can compare the values in `RowUpdating` between the cached and actual database before updating. However what are the chances that 2 users are actually updating the same row at the same time.